# Main application test always gives java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

Tags: mockito, junit5, spring-boot-test

I am trying to run main application test class. But it's always gives Failed to Load Application context

Application.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.aaa.abc","com.aaa.def" })
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitilizer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure (SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}
}
```

ApplicationTest.java

```
@SpringBootTest
class ApplicationTest {
@Test
void contextLoads() {
}
}
```

I tied by providing path of Application class in ApplicationTest class as specified below. But it's giving same exception

```
@SpringBootTest(classes={com.aaa.Application.class})
```

Comment: The test sources generally have a separate applicationContext.xml

Comment: It's spring boot app and don't have any XML configuration even for main sources